# API returning a structure

Tags: c, api, struct

What's the best solution for when:

- our API returns a structure to the user
- we want the user to be able to read its contents
- we don't want the user to change it, because it might be passed to some other API function and its contents should be correct?

Comment: You can't enforce "we don't want the user to change it" without  creating an opaque API to the data in some way.  That is really tedious.  I would say let the user do what they want; you cannot defend against misuse on every level.

Comment: Is it necessary to return a structure to the user, or is it acceptable to return a pointer to a structure? If so, you can return a pointer to a `const` structure. C only partially enforces this; an implementation should not permit modification through the pointer to the const structure, but it must permit the pointer to be converted to a pointer to non-const.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: this is actually my favorite idea in this thread so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function can return a pointer to a const structure. Then:

- The caller is not permitted to modify the structure through the pointer to the const structure. A C implementation should enforce this rule.
- If the caller passes the pointer to a const structure to another function in your API, the C rules permit that function to convert the pointer to a const structure to a pointer to a non-const structure. If the structure was not **defined** to be const (e.g., it was created as non-const, but a pointer to it was converted to a pointer to a const structure), then the function is permitted to modify the structure through the newly converted pointer to a non-const structure.
- The C rules also permit the caller to do this same conversion and modification. Obviously, the caller should not do this, and you are relying on their good will not to do so. Thus, this technique prevents inadvertent modifications through the returned pointer but does not prevent malicious modifications through a converted pointer.

To go further than that, you can provide the caller only with an incomplete declaration of the structure, one that reveals only its name (as in `struct foo;`) and does not define its contents (as in `struct foo { int x;… };`). When the caller has only an incomplete declaration of a structure, they can receive a pointer to the structure, and can store it and pass it as an argument, but they cannot use it to access the structure (except by abnormal means, such as converting it to a pointer to another type or by providing their own definition of the structure).

If the caller will have only an incomplete declaration of the structure but must be able to use contents of the structure, you must provide additional functions that accept a pointer to the structure as a parameter and return information from inside the structure.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning a structure return something that lets you restore the structure back (pointer to the structure should work, but you can use something else) and instead of letting user access its fields, give him a set of functions (or macros) for accessing these fields.

I think this is called opaque pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I think each time use call this function you can make a copy of this struct and return the copy to use .

In this way, each time the function called , a new copy create.

Aslo , you can let the user `malloc` a memeory and give API the address , API just use `memset` to fill the address , so the user can free the memory after they finish using data.

Also you can use a `opaque pointer`  if you did't want store the struct everywhere.

PS :I say the third suggestion in my command , then I get a downvote, while I see other man add this to his answer and get a upvote , and  we all don't have this line first, How this can happened!

Comment: Yeah, but it's the copy that gets passed to the other API functions.

Comment: @user2656304 No , each time function called , a new copy created.

Comment: Sorry, in fact there is no "copy", because we don't store the structure anywhere.

Comment: @user2656304 Then its hard to protect the struct from use's change, maybe you can use Joni's answer.

Comment: This seems like it will lead to massive inconsistencies in which `struct` instance is 'correct' or up-to-date.  In addition it is creating more room for memory management issues, and hides from the user the intention to keep the data private.  Use an opaque structure, or implement a `struct` with a private member variable that the user is not allowed to access.  This could be hidden behind a `void *` so that the user cannot dereference the private data even if she wanted to.

Comment: @ldrumm I just give a way , maybe not good enough , but it can solve the problem, right?  And I also tell the man to use  **opaque pointer** in my command.  And a not  good enough  way is not a bad way.

Comment: @LidongGuo I appreciate that you have thought of an answer, but I think this disregard for management of resources is potentially damaging, hence the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want users to mess with the struct internals you could return an [opaque pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) that can only be read using accessor functions that you define.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way you can stop the user accessing the contents of the structure. If this is a requirement, you'll have to return an opaque value and add an API to take one of these opaque values and return the individual values from it.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the answers here, which suggest the use of an opaque `struct`:

In C, there are few methods to prevent people accessing your data.  If you are handing around `structs` as the parameters and return values of your public API there are some ways you can hide the data or *contractually oblige your user to not access said data*.

Probably the most obvious common usage of opaque `struct`s is the `<stdio.h>` `FILE *`.  Any time you read/write/query a file using the standard library, you simply pass your `struct FILE  *` to one of the libc I/O functions such as `fwrite`.  Looking into the structure causes undefined behaviour because it's not guaranteed to be the same implementation across platforms.

If you want your user to be able to modify some data but not others you can do something like the following:

```
typedef struct 
{
    void * _my_private_data; //KEEP OUT
    char * name;
    int count;
    //etc
}my_api_type;
```

You can then define the first parameter of all function calls exposed to your user to take one of those `structs`:

`my_api_type set_internal_flag(my_api_type * obj, int flag);`

Having ensured that your private data remains hidden, your implementation can guarantee that that regardless of how you define the struct behind the `void *` your API functions can stay compatible across spec changes and the users won't have to modify their code when something gets updated.